# Could someone please translate 'Remember you must die, so remember to live'

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I really would like to get this as a tattoo but want to make sure the translation is correct. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Related 1](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17141/how-do-you-say-live-life-in-latin); [related 2](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14916/how-do-i-say-remember-death-but-do-not-forget-to-live-in-latin).

Answer (score 6):

A good translation for “remember to live” was given in [this related question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14916/how-do-i-say-remember-death-but-do-not-forget-to-live-in-latin) by TKR:

> ne obliviscaris vivere

… although that literally means “do not forget to live.” If you want to use this – and I assume you want to incorporate the very famous *memento mori* – then we get:

> Memento mori, quare ne obliviscaris vivere.

Literally: “Remember you must die, therefore do not forget to live.”

A repetition of *memento* would be quite ugly in my opinion. There would be the problem that *memento mori* should be read as “remember that you must die,” but *memento vivere* as “remember to live” (see the discussion [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/parallels-for-the-infinitive-in-memento-mori)), which I find irritating.

---

The shortness of life, the inevitability of death, and the need to make good use of the time we have got, is a subject that Latin writers throughout the ages have written on. Perhaps the most famous text in this regard is the student song [*Gaudeamus igitur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaudeamus_igitur), which goes, to quote just the first stanza:

> Gaudeamus igitur,
> Iuvenes dum sumus.
> Post iucundam iuventutem,
> Post molestam senectutem
> Nos habebit humus.
>
> So let us be happy
> While we are young.
> After a joyful youth
> And a troublesome old age
> We will rest in the ground.

The first two lines are, I think, essentially a different way to look at the sentiment you want to express. But unfortunately, they strongly evoke an old-fashioned and stuffy type of academic merriment as well.

Another well-known example is Seneca's [first letter to Lucilius](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/sen/seneca.ep1.shtml) (an English translation is available [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moral_letters_to_Lucilius/Letter_1)), famous because it is short, easy to translate (although the [devil is in the detail](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/are-magna-and-maxima-incorrectly-translated-in-these-examples-seneca-epist)), and, well, it is the first, so lots of students get to enjoy it during their Latin education.

Here are some formulations we can steal from Seneca:

> Vindica te tibi!

Literally: “liberate yourself” or “lay claim to yourself,” this means to stop time being stolen or slip away from yourself. (It means this in context, there is nothing in *vindicare* referring to time specifically.)

Another one:

> Omnes horas complectere.

English: “Seize [or: embrace] every hour.” (Seneca goes on: *Sic fiet ut minus ex crastino pendeas, si hodierno manum inieceris.* → That way you will depend less on tomorrow, if you grasp today with your hand.) An alternative to the terribly overused *Carpe diem*.

Comment: I really like the alternative suggestions. I do think *carpe diem* is a bit unfairly sneered at for being overused (not its fault!), but then again, the context of the poem would make people think twice about using it.

Comment: I really like your first suggestion. Do you think that *quare* is the best option here, or are there better ones?